# Not able to see Consul UI

Tags: docker-compose, consul

I am not able to see Consul ui. I am currently using this docker-compose file. Don't know what I am missing.

```
version: '3'
services: 
  consul:
    container_name: consul
    hostname: consul
    image: progrium/consul
    volumes:
      - /data
      - /config
      - ./consul/consul_ui:/ui
    ports:
      - "8300:8300"
      - "8400:8400"
      - "8500:8500"
      - "8600:8600"
    environment:
    - DOCKER_IP=$DOCKER_IP
    command: -server -bootstrap -data-dir /data -ui-dir /ui
```

Comment: Please share the consul config file as well. It has to do something with consul config file.